# declare a n-pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, c-preprocessor

In C, I want to declare a n-dimension array like the following 3-dim.

```
printf("please insert n1, n2, n3\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);

int ***nda;
nda = (int ***)malloc(n1*sizeof(int **));

for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    nda[i] = malloc(n2*sizeof(int *));
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        nda[i][j] = malloc(n3*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

I want to automate this process using macro and expand to n-dim and I found I need to declare a pointer like this:

```
type *...*(n times)typename;
```

I guess macro is a seemingly possible way to do this, but after searching answers here, I found that macro does not expand recursively.
Are there any workarounds to do this in C?

Comment: Since the code is compiled, what is the use for the typename at runtime?

Comment: Something tells me the problem here isn't declaring a pointer to n-levels of indirection. Rather it seems, it would be *why* you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have changed the question.

Comment: @user2690457 This indeed seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses, I would give the whole picture of what I want to do.

Comment: Check out Boost preprocessor (which is not tied to C++).  You can create a macro to be executed N times to achieve N stars, where N is a macro parameter.  Whether that's a good idea is a separate discussion; you'll need to handle the memory allocation quite a bit differently for the N = 4, 5, 6 ... cases; you can't go on nesting loops indefinitely as your code currently does.

Comment: Why do you want macros?, you can declare a function with `n` and `sizeof object` as arguments and make it alloc/init everything.

Answer (score 3):

Stop doing what you do right now! Each level of pointer indirection adds a significant performance hit to your program. What you're creating there is not a multidimensional array, it's a n-ary tree, where each array element is a pointer to a number of branches, that spread out again.

If you want to create an array for n-dimensional data do it this way:

```
size_t dim[...]

int *nda;
nda = malloc(sizeof(int) * dim[0] * dim[1] * … * dim[n]);
```

To address an element in the array use this

```
nda[ dim[0]*(i[1] + dim[1]*(i[2] + dim[…]*(i[…+1])) + i[0] ];
```

Comment: @Will: This works only so far without getting deep into hard to read syntactic cruft. You can not in-scope cast to a VLA; you have to write something like `void foo(size_t dim_a, size_t dim_b, elementtype data[dim_a][dim_b])` to get a malloc-ed memory area into VLA shape. This is not very flexible and the "cruft" as you call it is not very hard to work it. It's idiomatic and once you've done it enough times you just "read over" it, without parsing each substatement (just in the same way you don't read these lines character by character).

Comment: @Will: Well, there's also the problem with using C99 features (and I'm writing this as a C99 fan, just look at the sources of my projects) is, that unfortunately some compilers still don't support it fully (MSVC I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 1):

Although doing this is a bad idea, it *can* be done, so here's one way.

You can in fact loop in the preprocessor, and define recursive macros, if you use a suitably powerful metaprogramming library like [Order](https://github.com/VesaKarvonen/order-pp) (as mentioned above Boost is another possible candidate). Order lets you program in a functional style familiar to anyone who knows Scheme or ML.

To loop, use a `for_each` construct. To simply create a given number of something you can use `for_each_in_range` with `1, N+1`:

```
ORDER_PP(    // within this block Order code runs
    8for_each_in_range(8fn(8_, 8print( (*) ) ),
                       1, 8)
)
```

The above will print 7 stars. You can wrap up metaprogram blocks inside conventional macros, which follow normal preprocessor rules:

```
// print COUNT stars
#define STARS(COUNT) ORDER_PP( \
    8for_each_in_range(8fn(8_, 8print((*)) ), 1, 8plus(COUNT, 1)) \
)
```

Within the `ORDER_PP` block, everything is assumed to be Order code rather than C Preprocessor code, which means only recognised Order functions can be called (and all values/preprocessing tokens must be either raw ints, or "quoted" with the `8(val)` construct). To define `stars` as an Order function instead of a CPP macro, so that it can be called from within `ORDER_PP` as part of a nested expression, we need to write it like this:

```
#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8stars ORDER_PP_FN( \
    8fn(8C, 8for_each_in_range(8fn(8_, 8print((*)) ), 1, 8plus(8C, 1)) ))

ORDER_PP( 8stars(7) )   // prints 7 stars
```

Order provides recursion completely transparently, so writing the nested initializer loops is relatively straightforward:

```
#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8ndim_init ORDER_PP_FN( \
    8fn(8N, 8T, 8C, 8I, 8D, \
        8do( \
            8print( 8N (=malloc) 8lparen 8seq_head(8D) (*sizeof) 8lparen 8T 8stars(8minus(8C, 1)) 8rparen 8rparen (;) ), \
            8if(8equal(8C, 1), \
                8print(((void)0;)), \
                8do( \
                    8print( (for) 8lparen (int) 8I (=0;) 8I (<) 8seq_head(8D) (;) 8I (++) 8rparen ({) ), \
                    8ndim_init(8adjoin(8N, 8([), 8I, 8(])), 8T, 8minus(8C, 1), 8cat(8I, 8(_K)), 8seq_tail(8D)), \
                    8print( (}) ) \
                )))))
```

Invoke `ndim_init` like this:

```
// print the nested initializer from the question
ORDER_PP(
    8ndim_init(8(nda), 8(int), 3, 8(i), 8seq(8(n1), 8(n2), 8(n3)))
)
```

Notice that the C variable names (`nda`, `i`, etc.) need to be quoted when appearing within the `ORDER_PP` block so that Order treats them as text, instead of trying to evaluate them. The last argument is a list of the runtime variables that will contain the sizes for each dimension (`8seq` builds a list, `8` again quotes the C variable names).

You can package the invocation of `ndim_init` up in a regular preprocessor macro for easy access, much like the first example with `STARS`; you can combine it with a declarator macro easily in this way, to emit declaration and initialization in a single call:

```
#define NDIM(NAME, TYPE, ...) ORDER_PP ( \
    8lets( (8D, 8((__VA_ARGS__))) \
           (8C, 8tuple_size(8D)), \
        8do( \
            8print( (TYPE) 8stars(8C) (NAME; {) ), \
            8ndim_init(8(NAME), 8(TYPE), 8C, 8(_ITER), 8tuple_to_seq(8D)), \
            8print( (}) ) \
        )) \
)

NDIM(nda, int, n1, n2, n3)   // emits declaration and init block for int ***nda
```

[More Order examples](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order)

---

If the above didn't seem straightforward at all... that's why people say you shouldn't do it. (If it did, good for you, nobody else will be able to read your code though.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with variable length arrays (requires C99 or newer). In this case, because of its potentional size, the VLA is not allocated on the stack, but manually with (m/c)alloc():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DIM_C 10
#define MAX_DIM_SIZE 100

// Works for versions of C from C99 onward.

int main(void) {
    int dim_c;
    do {
        printf("Please input the number of dimensions. "
               "The minimum value is 1. The maximum value is %d.\n",
               MAX_DIM_C);
    } while (scanf("%d", &dim_c) != 1 || dim_c < 1 || dim_c > 100);
    int dim[MAX_DIM_C];
    // Give all dimensions a default size of 1.
    memset(dim, 1, MAX_DIM_C);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim_c; i++) {
        do {
            printf("Please input the size of dimension %d. "
                   "The minimum value is 1. The maximum value is %d.\n",
                   i, MAX_DIM_SIZE);
        } while (scanf("%d", dim + i) != 1 || dim[i] < 1 || dim[i] > 100);
    }
    // Always allocate a MAX_DIM_C-dimensional array. When the user specifies
    // a number of dimensions fewer than MAX_DIM_C, the MAX_DIM_C-dim_c
    // dimensions are basically just dummy dimensions of size 1
    int (*vla)[dim[1]]
              [dim[2]]
              [dim[3]]
              [dim[4]]
              [dim[5]]
              [dim[6]]
              [dim[7]]
              [dim[8]]
              [dim[9]] =
        calloc(dim[0] *
               dim[1] *
               dim[2] *
               dim[3] *
               dim[4] *
               dim[5] *
               dim[6] *
               dim[7] *
               dim[8] *
               dim[9], sizeof(int));
    //
    // Do something useful here
    //
    printf("%d\n", vla[dim[0] - 1]
                      [dim[1] - 1]
                      [dim[2] - 1]
                      [dim[3] - 1]
                      [dim[4] - 1]
                      [dim[5] - 1]
                      [dim[6] - 1]
                      [dim[7] - 1]
                      [dim[8] - 1]
                      [dim[9] - 1]);
    // To pass the VLA to another function cast it to void (or another simple
    // type) and also pass the dim array along with it to generate a new
    // VLA pointer in the called function with matching dimensions
    return 0;
}
```